# Jenkins Kubernetes Plugin URL Connection Fails After Some Time

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, ibm-cloud, jenkins-kubernetes, kubernetes-jenkins-plugin

I run into a strange issue, as the title suggests.

I am running my Jenkins on a Kubernetes cluster on IBM Cloud. I used the kubernetes plugin to configure a cloud and dynamically create a slave container to run jobs.

When I set up this cloud configuration, I provided the Kubernetes Public Service Endpoint URL (as I found on some other guides) of the cluster that Jenkins is on, as the Kubernetes URL. I can test it and it works successfully.

Strangely, after running a few jobs, it starts to give me errors that It cant start the containers.

If I go back into the cloud configuration, and click "Test Connection", it now throws an error: `Error testing connection https://<Public Service Endpoint URL>: null`. If I restart Jenkins, it works again.

Any advise is much appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why it ***sometimes*** worked with using the Public Service Endpoint, but posting this for future people:

1. I created `clusterrolebinding` as per [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48853727/11097901)
2. I created a credential (type: secret text) and used it with "Kubernetes URL" of `https://kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local` for the cloud configuration